# Keynote: table cell align right with padding

Tags: macos, keynote

I am using Keynote 7.x on Mac OS High Sierra. I created a table of numbers, and for a particular column, I want to align right with some padding on the right.

As shown in the figure below, I applied "align right" to the column `foo`. Now I want to add some padding between the number and the margin of the cell.

[image]

Below are the controls for the cell, but I don't see any options. I tried the "indent" control, but it didn't do anything.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Increase the **Text Inset** option shown in your screenshot to add padding to the cell.

This adds padding to all sides (including the right), which may increase row height. It looks like you've already got some spare height to work with, so it shouldn't affect the height if you limit how much you increment it by.

Alternatively if the additional spacing on the top/bottom is an issue and you have numerical data in your cells, you can add fake spacing to the end of numerical data with a **custom number format**:

1. Select your cells/column and in the inspector choose Cell → Data Format → Create Custom Format….
2. Add spaces to the end of the format string. Add multiple spaces and customise their width if necessary.

   [image]

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but as you said, it increases padding on all four sides. The table is actually pretty packed, so I can't afford adding more padding on the top and bottom of each cell.

Comment: @stack See edit, number formats might be a solution?

Comment: That's great improvisation. It's disappointing that Keynote doesn't provide a more direct solution.

Comment: actually I always used the same system (custom format) in Excel, to add spaces or any other characters for padding in the cells... but I understand that one can question the choice of not providing a separate padding for the 4 sides of a cell

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you're looking after using the `Indents` section in your screenshot. Add `Right` value.

Comment: OP said in the question that ‘I tried the "indent" control, but it didn't do anything’, perhaps you could add some more details to your answer?

Comment: I missed that part. But the answer is that easy and I don't have anything to add. BTW I leave the answer for those people who read the Question title and answers, and not the question body.

Answer (score 0):

As your screenshot indicates, right indent is actually working but only for the text field (hence you see that "foo" is indented while the numbers are not).

To resolve this issue:

1. Select the column you need indented. Go to Format - Data format and select "Text" as your data format **even for number fields**.
2. Go to Text - Layout - Indents, and apply Right indent you need.

Have no idea why Right indent is not applied to "Number" data formats, but Apple is a small indie company, we can not ask too much from them :)